# Rails 4, recaptcha and turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, recaptcha, turbolinks

I'm trying to implement recaptcha in one of my forms. I'm using the code below in my form

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
</script>
<noscript>
  <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key"
     height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
   <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
   </textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
     value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

If I follow a link onto the page that contains the recaptcha, it isn't shown. If I then reload the page using the browser then it is shown.

I've figured it out that this is due to using turbolinks.

I know placing `data-no-turbolink` in the body tag prevents turbolinks for that page and this works, but I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it and if i want to disable it for the whole page just to get recpatcha working (seems hacky).

I also enclosed the recaptcha code in a div and put `data-no-turbolink` in the tag but that didn't work.

Is there a way to disable turbolinks just for the form with the recaptcha or is there another way I should be trying to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom it may concern - there is also a simple ajax fix according to the bug report on github (http://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/83#issuecomment-30019798).

Simply use:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags ajax: true %>
```

Worked just fine for me!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Here it is: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/83

Disabled turbolinks for the whole page.

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name), "data-no-turbolink" => true %><br />
```

Comment: To whom it may concern - there is also a simple ajax fix according to the bug report on github (https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/83#issuecomment-30019798): simply use <%= recaptcha_tags ajax: true %> - worked just fine for me!

Comment: @Ben, you should post this as an answer, in my opinion. It works and it is more efficient than this answer.